# PDO: Why i can't pull my own post, but I can pull the posts of the users following form MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with my SQL code. I am trying to create a newsfeed like facebook using PDO. My problem is that the best i can come up with, is that its pulling all the posts of the users am following but not my own posts. Cant seem to find the problem.

Heres the database structure:

user_table: `user_id, username, name`

posts: `post_id, body, user_id, likes`

followers: `id, user_id, follower_id`

Connection script:

```
 class DB {

    private static function connect() {
            $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8','root','');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
            $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($params);
            if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
            }
    }
 }

?>`
```

script for pulling posts:

```
$posts = DB::query('SELECT posts.post_id, posts.body, posts.likes, users_table.`username`, users_table.`name` FROM users_table, posts, followers
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
AND users_table.user_id = posts.user_id
AND follower_id = :userid
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC', array(':userid'=>$userid));
```

Any ideas? been looking all over the internet for solutions, cant seem to find what am looking for.

Comment: You're only ever selecting from followers.user_id so your current user isn't listed as one of it's own followers I'm guessing.

Comment: Yes it's not. Are you saying that the current user must also follow itself?

Comment: The answer below explains this more but either a user follows them self or you change your where clause

Comment: Your answer was the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this problem is for the current user to follow itself to get to also pull its own posts and be displayed on the current user's newsfeed .

Answer (score 0):

Because You are selecting only posts from your followers as stated in,

```
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
```

So, you might change that line like,

```
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id or posts.user_id = user.user_id
```

Where your `user.user_id` refers to your own `ID`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it displays every post twice, including the current user posts

Comment: try `DISTINCT`.

Comment: How would I use that?